# How to invert a permutation represented by an array in-place

Tags: c++

I tried to write a function that would invert an array and print its [inverse permutation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inverse-permutation/) without creating a new array.

> Given an array of size n of integers in range from 1 to n, we need to find the inverse permutation of that array.

> An inverse permutation is a permutation which you will get by inserting position of an element at the position specified by the element value in the array.

I wrote code that can invert giving an output array, but I have to create a new array in order to do that. **How to do it in-place?**

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void inverse(int arr[], int size) {
  int arr2[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    arr2[arr[i] - 1] = i + 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << arr2[i] << " ";
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 1};
  int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  inverse(arr, size);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194973/discussion-on-question-by-raunaq-singh-how-to-inverse-an-array-without-forming-a).

Comment: This is valid and good question. Algorithm in-place are good because you don't need to allocate new memory.

Answer (score 1):

I really wish you code it by yourself, here is how I would do it:

Take two variables, one pointing at the start of array another at last
swap the elements at both positions
increment start and decrement end pointer respectively
repeat the steps while start pointer is less than end pointer

Edit1:
Here you go:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inverse-permutation/

No other solution shall be working for your situation

I understand that you are looking for a different approach, but let's discuss the feasibility here:

You need to store the value you are going to replace, for future reference, else you are going to lose track of it!
One might argue that we shall keep a 'visited' flag for convenience but that just makes the code more ugly, complicated and complex, doesn't really help. So, in my opinion, a solution other than given is not practical at all!

Comment: That's how to reverse the array, but it's not what this code with the new array does.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but as the description says he is looking for the same.

Comment: He wrote "inverse an array", someone else edited it to say "reverse an array". It's not clear that's what he really meant.

Comment: He claims that the code he wrote works except for needing a new array. It doesn't reverse the array, it does something else.

Comment: I've edited the question. I want to know how to find the inverse of an array.

Comment: @RaunaqSingh You haven't explained what "inverse of an array" means. Your function prints the 1-based index of each number in the array.

Comment: The definition of "inverse" has been added to the question. It's not the same as "reverse".

Comment: @RaunaqSingh The approaches mentioned at geeks for geeks are best ways, no other approach would be worth considering given the randomness and complexity it would induce.You must store the value at index you are going to edit, before you do anything on that index, else you loose data

Comment: My code matches the code geeks for geeks has given. I wanted to learn a different approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'm not looking for the solution geeks for geeks has. I'm looking for a solution in which we don't have to form a temporary array. Why don't you give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I found this very recent paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.01926.pdf, where all is nicely typeset an explained.
Apparently there is always a compromise between time and space complexity and there is no algorithm (yet?) that is O(n)-in-time and in-place.
(The paper claims to be the first subquadratic deterministic in-place algorithm.)

The algorithm you posted is not listed in the paper and would be O(n) in time and O(n) in space (i.e. out-of-place).

I post it here for reference, also to check the correctness of other implementations.
I used zero-base indexing for simplicity.

```
// O(n) out-of-place algorithm
template<class It, class Size, class ItOut>
void inverse_permutation_n(It first, Size n, ItOut d_first){
    for(Size i = 0; i != n; ++i){
        d_first[first[i]] = i;
    }
}
```

Then there is the algorithm that is listed as "folklore" in the table translated from the pseudocode in the paper (Listing 3 in the paper).

```
#include<algorithm> // for std::min

template<class It, class Index>
void reverse_cycle(It t, Index start){
    auto cur = t[start];
    auto prev = start;
    while( cur != start ){
        auto next = t[cur];
        t[cur] = prev;
        prev = cur;
        cur = next;
    }
    t[start] = prev;
}

template<class It, class Index>
auto cycle_leader(It t, Index start){
    auto cur = t[start];
    auto smallest = start;
    while(cur != start){
        smallest = std::min(smallest, cur);
        cur = t[cur];
    }
    return smallest;
}

// O(n²) in-place algorithm
template<class It, class Size>
void inverse_permutation_n(It first, Size n){
    for(Size i = 0; i != n; ++i){
        if( cycle_leader(first, i) == i ) reverse_cycle(first, i);
    }
}
```

The above algorithm is O(n²)-time in the average case.
The reason is that for each point you have to follow a cycle of length O(n) to find the leader.

---

Then you can build on top of this by putting a shortcut in the cycle leader search, once the cycle leader is less than the starting point the search returns false.

```
template<class It, class Index>
auto cycle_leader_shortcut(It t, Index start){
    auto cur = t[start];
    while(cur != start){
        if(cur < start) return false;
        cur = t[cur];
    }
    return true;
}

// O(n log n) in-place algorithm
template<class It, class Size>
void inverse_permutation_shortcut_n(It first, Size n){
    for(Size i = 0; i != n; ++i){
        if( cycle_leader_shortcut(first, i) ) reverse_cycle(first, i);
    }
}
```

This algorithm is fortunately O(N log N) (in average, I think).
The reason is that the cycles iteration become shorter as the point in the sequence increases because it is more likely that a point will have a low value that was already reversed.

---

This is the benchmark and the result:

```
#include<numeric> // for iota
#include<random>

// initialize rng
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

static void BM_inverse_permutation(benchmark::State& state){

    // allocate memory and initialize test buffer and reference solution
    auto permutation = std::vector<std::size_t>(state.range(0)); 
    std::iota(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), 0);

    auto reference_inverse_permutation = std::vector<std::size_t>(permutation.size());

    for(auto _ : state){
        state.PauseTiming(); // to random shuffle and calculate reference solution
        std::shuffle(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), g);
    //    inverse_permutation_n(permutation.cbegin(), permutation.size(), reference_inverse_permutation.begin());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(permutation.data());
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
        state.ResumeTiming();

        inverse_permutation_n(permutation.begin(), permutation.size());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(permutation.data());
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();

    //  state.PauseTiming(); // to check that the solution is correct
    //  if(reference_inverse_permutation != permutation) throw std::runtime_error{""};
    //  state.ResumeTiming();
    }

    state.SetItemsProcessed(state.iterations()*permutation.size()                    );
    state.SetComplexityN(state.range(0));
}

BENCHMARK(BM_inverse_permutation)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(8, 8<<10)->Complexity(benchmark::oNSquared);

static void BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut(benchmark::State& state){

    // allocate memory and initialize test buffer and reference solution
    auto permutation = std::vector<std::size_t>(state.range(0)); 
    std::iota(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), 0);

    auto reference_inverse_permutation = std::vector<std::size_t>(permutation.size());

    for(auto _ : state){
        state.PauseTiming(); // to random shuffle and calculate reference solution
        std::shuffle(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), g);
    //    inverse_permutation_n(permutation.cbegin(), permutation.size(), reference_inverse_permutation.begin());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(permutation.data());
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
        state.ResumeTiming();

        inverse_permutation_shortcut_n(permutation.begin(), permutation.size());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(permutation.data());
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();

    //    state.PauseTiming(); // to check that the solution is correct
    //    if(reference_inverse_permutation != permutation) throw std::runtime_error{""};
    //    state.ResumeTiming();
    }

    state.SetItemsProcessed(state.iterations()*permutation.size()                    );
    state.SetComplexityN(state.range(0));
}

BENCHMARK(BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(8, 8<<10)->Complexity(benchmark::oNLogN);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

```sh
$ c++ a.cpp -O3 -DNDEBUG -lbenchmark && ./a.out
2021-03-30 21:16:55
Running ./a.out
Run on (12 X 4600 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32K (x6)
  L1 Instruction 32K (x6)
  L2 Unified 256K (x6)
  L3 Unified 12288K (x1)
Load Average: 1.26, 1.80, 1.76
***WARNING*** CPU scaling is enabled, the benchmark real time measurements may be noisy and will incur extra overhead.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                     Time             CPU   Iterations UserCounters...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_inverse_permutation/8                    476 ns          478 ns      1352259 items_per_second=16.7276M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/16                   614 ns          616 ns      1124905 items_per_second=25.9688M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/32                  1106 ns         1107 ns       630398 items_per_second=28.9115M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/64                  2929 ns         2931 ns       238236 items_per_second=21.835M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/128                10748 ns        10758 ns        64708 items_per_second=11.898M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/256                41556 ns        41582 ns        16600 items_per_second=6.15656M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/512               164006 ns       164023 ns         4245 items_per_second=3.12151M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/1024              621341 ns       620840 ns         1056 items_per_second=1.64938M/s
BM_inverse_permutation/2048             2468060 ns      2466060 ns          293 items_per_second=830.474k/s
BM_inverse_permutation/4096            10248540 ns     10244982 ns           93 items_per_second=399.805k/s
BM_inverse_permutation/8192            55926122 ns     55926230 ns           10 items_per_second=146.479k/s
BM_inverse_permutation_BigO                0.82 N^2        0.82 N^2  
BM_inverse_permutation_RMS                   18 %            18 %    
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/8           499 ns          501 ns      1193871 items_per_second=15.9827M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/16          565 ns          567 ns      1225056 items_per_second=28.2403M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/32          740 ns          742 ns       937909 items_per_second=43.1509M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/64         1121 ns         1121 ns       619016 items_per_second=57.0729M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/128        1976 ns         1977 ns       355982 items_per_second=64.745M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/256        3644 ns         3645 ns       191387 items_per_second=70.2375M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/512        7282 ns         7288 ns        95434 items_per_second=70.2481M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/1024      14732 ns        14752 ns        47417 items_per_second=69.4165M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/2048      30590 ns        30398 ns        23079 items_per_second=67.3728M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/4096      64374 ns        64039 ns        10766 items_per_second=63.9613M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut/8192     196961 ns       195786 ns         3646 items_per_second=41.8416M/s
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut_BigO       1.74 NlgN       1.73 NlgN 
BM_inverse_permutation_shortcut_RMS          27 %            27 %
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach, I permutate cycles and flag what has been done by adding an offset equal to the size of the array to the newly set values. Only after all the cycles have been permutated do I remove the offset. It's as simple as I could make it.

```
void index_value_permutation(size_t *a, size_t n)
{
    size_t i, i1, i2, ic=0;

start:
    // Look for next cycle
    for (; ic < n; ic++)
        if (a[ic] != ic && a[ic] < n)
            break;
    i = ic;
    ic++;

    // If a cycle was found
    if (i < n)
    {
        i1 = a[i];

        // Permutate this cycle
        while (a[i1] < n)
        {
            i2 = a[i1]; // save the original value
            a[i1] = i + n;  // add n to signal it as being permutated
            i = i1;
            i1 = i2;
        }

        goto start;
    }

    // Remove the n offset
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] >= n)
            a[i] -= n;
}
```